# VS Code Color XML tag on content

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to configure a rule to provide another color for certain tags based on content.

E.g: I want to have a distinguished color for tags named "Transitions".

```xml
<item>
    <Transitions>
        <!-- Stuff -->
    </Transitions>
</item>
```

Can someone help me in how i can achieve that? I found descriptions how to change the color based on textmate scopes for all tags.

Comment: use the extension **Highlight**

Comment: I tried. Was not able to find the correct configuration. Or maybe i did not try the correct extension. Could you explain how i can achive that with a link to the extension.

Comment: @rioV8 i just realized that there is an extension called high-lite (there is another extension incapable of doing what i wanted that has a similar name). I tired the extension and it works like a charm. Thx!